# How to execute a @task.group from another dag Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I have a custom library that I can't modify, and it has the following task.group:

```
@task_group(group_id="send_kafka")
def send_kafka(data: dict, reg):
    """Process to send msg to kafka."""
    for type in reg:
        if type is False:
            group_id = "get_namefile"
        else:
            group_id = "get_namefile_" + str(type).lower()
        @task_group(group_id=group_id)
        def send_data(data: dict):
            key_json = get_files_names(data, type)
            json_key = parquet_s3_json(key_json)
            end_json = send_kafka(json_key)
            notify_slack(end_json)
        send_data(data)
```

My goal is to create a new DAG that performs validation and, if successful, executes the entire 'send_kafka' group."

I have tried the following.

```
@task.branch(task_id='first_execution')
def first_execution(metadata):
    """Check if has already been processed, and if so, do not execute the sending."""
    sf_hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id=snowflake_conn_id)
    with sf_hook.get_conn() as conn:
        value = execute_query(query, conn)
    if value == 0:
        return 'send_kafka'

 @dag(schedule_interval=None,
     max_active_runs=1,
     start_date=datetime(2023, 8, 1),
     default_args=default_args,
     catchup=False,
     doc_md=doc_md)

def validate():
    """Dag."""
    data = fetch_metadata()
    first_execution(data) >> send_kafka(data, reg)


dag = validate()
```

And it generates an error.
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Branch callable must return valid task_ids. Invalid tasks found: {'send_kafka'}

I tried it in the following way

```
from airflow.decorators import dag
from airflow.contrib.hooks.snowflake_hook import SnowflakeHook
from airflow.decorators import task
from dags.utils import send_kafka, execute_query


@dag(schedule_interval=None,
     max_active_runs=1,
     start_date=datetime(2023, 8, 1),
     default_args=default_args,
     catchup=False,
     doc_md=doc_md)

def validate():
    """Dag."""
    data = fetch_metadata()

    @task.branch(task_id='first_execution')
    def first_execution(metadata):
    """Check if has already been processed, and if so, do not execute 
       the sending."""
    table = metadata['table']
    query = f'SELECT COUNT(CAMP1) FROM {table}'
    sf_hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id=snowflake_conn_id)
    with sf_hook.get_conn() as conn:
        value = execute_query(query, conn)
    if value == 0:
        return list(send_kafka(data, reg).roots)[0].task_id


    first_execution(data) >> send_kafka(data, reg)
dag = validate()

the new error is airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: TaskGroup can only be used inside a dag
```

Answer (score 1):

The Tasks ids under a group get a new id with convention : group_id.task_id

also, you need to call the first task in the group, in case you don't know its name you can get it by code (get from the group the first root task - last row in the code example)

```
group = send_kafka(data, reg)

@task.branch(task_id='first_execution')
def first_execution(metadata):
    """Check if has already been processed, and if so, do not execute the sending."""
    sf_hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id=snowflake_conn_id)
    with sf_hook.get_conn() as conn:
        value = execute_query(query, conn)
    if value == 0:
        return list(group.roots)[0].task_id
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?, I tried it in the following way, Put my task.id 'first_execution' inside the DAG in order to be able to invoke the task.group., But it throws the following error. `airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: TaskGroup can only be used inside a dag`

Comment: Sure, if you can update the code in the question  it be easier for me to explain

Comment: I think you should move all tasks under validate function

Comment: I just updated the code as I tested it; it's in the last part. The reason for moving it inside the function is that fetch_metadata() returns a pre-processed dataset to be used in validating first_execution and using it in the query before executing the task.group send_kafka

Comment: I see few problems : 1. fetch_data happends every 30 sec because its in the the high python code that airflow refresh all the time. not a good practice. better create a task that runs when dags schedueld . 2. send_kafka is defined outside the dag so you should apply the day to this task_group. 3. you call send_kafka twice which creates 2 different tasks (with 2 different ids). see my example how to avoid it